# syntax when inserting a varible into an url in curl_init()

Tags: php, curl, syntax

I need to insert an id-variable into the link "https://api.quickpay.net/payments/9727866/link" (instead of "9727866") but i can't seem to get the syntax right.

It doesn't seem to accept my variables no matter what I do.. anyone knows how to do this?

```
   $params = array(
       "amount"            => 100,
       "order_id"       => 999999
   );                                                                    
   $data_string = http_build_query($params, '&'); 

   $headers = array(
          'Accept-Version: v10',
          'Accept: application/json', 
          'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode(":HIDDEN_API_KEY")
      );                                                                                  

   $ch = curl_init('https://api.quickpay.net/payments/9727866/link');                                                                      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   if(!curl_exec($ch)){
       die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);

   print_r($result);
```

Comment: `$ch = curl_init(".....{$var_with_id}/link")`? Just because it's a url doesn't make it magically special. it's text, like any other text in PHP.

Comment: "no matter what I do"  Where exactly is it that you're doing something that is an attempt to make this work?

Comment: hmm... so what you're saying is this?:

$ch = curl_init('https://api.quickpay.net/payments/{$payment_id}/link'); 

my editor doesn't reconize that as a variable...

Comment: @spazoid Double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're using single quotes. Try any of the following:

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://api.quickpay.net/payments/$variable/link");
```

or

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.quickpay.net/payments/{$variable}/link");
```

or

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.quickpay.net/payments/" . $variable . "/link");
```

or

```
$str = "https://api.quickpay.net/payments/" . $variable . "/link";
$ch = curl_init($str);
```

or

```
sprintf("https://api.quickpay.net/payments/%s/link", $variable);
```

Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: ah lol, i didn't dare changing the qoutations, as it's some 3rd party code i generally don't understand how fully works... i wonder why a PSP would use single qoutes in their example, when it _always_ has to contain a variable in order to work :)

anyway, thanks for the quick and efficient help!

Comment: you forgot `sprintf("https://api.quickpay.net/payments/%s/link", $variable);` , `implode('', ['https://api.quickpay.net/payments/', $variable, '/link']);` and probably some really horrible regex i havent thought up yet

Comment: @Steve True, might as well add sprintf. You're missing a closing bracket on implode btw.